# Attachment with SOAP Handler using CXF

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I'm trying to attach a file with a SOAP Handler using Apache CXF, but it doesn't work.

My example is here.

https://github.com/emag-notes/cxf-soaphandler-demo

In this example, I use SAAJ API to attach a file.

https://github.com/emag-notes/cxf-soaphandler-demo/blob/master/server/src/main/java/cxf/soaphandler/AttachmentHandler.java#L49-L54

However, the SOAP Message response is a just SOAP Envelope, not multipart(not
including the file I attached).

Am I missing something? This code works with Apache Axis2.

Even though I know using MTOM is the best option, I'd like to use my existing codes AMAP for now(I'm working on migration from Axis2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the code looks fine, I believe you need to juest enable MTOM, even though you are not using full features of MTOM.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

  <jaxws:server id="Downloader" serviceClass="cxf.soaphandler.Downloader" address="downloader">
    <jaxws:serviceBean>
      <bean class="cxf.soaphandler.Downloader">
      </bean>
    </jaxws:serviceBean>
    <jaxws:binding>
        <soap:soapBinding mtomEnabled="true" />
    </jaxws:binding>
  </jaxws:server>

</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! it's magic for me...
though it looks like mtom communication as far as seeing packet capture(Content type is application/xop_xml), my axis1 client can access the service.